# Download file from Android ownCloud Client

Tags: owncloud

How can I download a file from ownCloud storage to my Android device using ownCloud Client for Android?

So far, I only found the option 'make available offline', which stores the file in an encrypted folder not accessible by other programs or file explorers.

I'm currently using ownCloud Client for Android version 4.0-beta.2.

The only way I found was using the web interface and not the ownCloud Client, but that's quite tedious.